# Location of db/config.yml on a ruby app using standalone-migrations

Tags: ruby, database, configuration-files

I'm working on an command-line application that uses the [standalone_migrations gem](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations). I have the `db/config.yml` file and everything works fine when I run the app from the root dir, but when I run it from other dirs (e.g. directly running a script in the /bin directory), the gem cannot find the db/config.yml.

I looked at the gem's source, specifically in the lib/configurator.rb file, but couldn't find a way to set the correct .yml path.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to directly run a script instead of using the `rake` tasks?

Comment: @JustinWood well, I want to be able to call the script from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

`StandaloneMigrations::Configurator` uses relative paths, it loads configuration files on line [#23](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations/blob/7447de9719aac53da4af698bb44dfb035746edb8/lib/standalone_migrations/configurator.rb#L23).

This is a bug in the code. A workaround could be to change the working directory to the root before you execute the script. You didn't mention what kind of script you have under `/bin`, but for example if it is a Bash script, you can do something like:

```
cd /project/directory && rake db:migrate ...
```